# NullPointerException at ActionListener

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why do I get this runtime ERROR?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at venzo.MVC_Controller.actionListenerMeth(MVC_Controller.java:40)
>
> at venzo.MVC_Controller.(MVC_Controller.java:15)

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class MVC_Controller implements ActionListener
{
MVC_Model model;
MVC_View view;
public MVC_Controller(MVC_View v,MVC_Model m)
{
model=m;
view=v;
actionListenerMeth(this);//add action listener to the Button
} 
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
try
{
   //retrieve the input from View
   String a=view.username.getText();
   String b=view.password.getText();

   //call add method
   String result=model.login_meth(a,b);

   //display result in View(UI)

   view.result_lb.setText(""+result);
}

catch(Exception ee)
{
ee.printStackTrace();
}  
}
 public void actionListenerMeth(ActionListener ae)
   {
      view.login_bt.addActionListener(ae);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to include enough of the stack trace to include the MVC_Controller class. Otherwise, there's no context to help you out.

Comment: check if view.login_bt is null ??

Comment: You should debug and check whether `view` or `view.login_bt` is `null`.

Comment: my guess is that either `view` or `view.login_bt` is null in the `actionListenerMeth(...)` call at the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it